# Chrome date field min/max silently "corrects" year

Tags: html, validation, google-chrome, date

I have an HTML form that includes type=date fields.  Each date field has a min/max value set as a basic sanity check since my users like to type into the form (rather than use date pickers) and they often type dates like "4/17/0213".

The form is submitted by a jquery ajax call which is triggered by a form submit.

All users are using Chrome as a browser.

When they type in a date completely that is out of range, date range validation works as it should.  When they merely change the *year*, or the year and one other part of the date (month or day, but not both), in an existing date so that it ends up outside the valid range, Chrome does not give them a validation error.  Instead, it **silently** "corrects" the year back to what it was previously so that it stays in the valid date range.  This results in garbage values getting silently submitted to the database.

I've tried writing my own validation routine in javascript, but it seems that the problem is that the underlying data value doesn't change to the invalid year, so trying to get it and check it is a waste of time.  As far as Chrome is concerned, the invalid year just wasn't typed.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

EDIT: I have included some code to demonstrate part of the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Date bug test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on("submit", "FORM", function(){
        $("#dateshow").html("Date entered was: " +  $("input[name=foo]").val());
        return true;
       });
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type=date name="foo" min='1980-01-01' max='2080-01-01' />
  <input type=text name="bar">
  <input type=submit>
</form>
<div id=dateshow></div>
</body>
```

To demonstrate:

- Save this to an html file and open in Chrome
- Enter a date between 1980 and 2080 into the date field and submit
- Date will be shown as submitted.
- Select **ONLY THE YEAR** in the date field and change it to a value outside the valid range
- Click submit again.
- Note that the date submitted *does not change*, even though your invalid date still shows in the form control.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add to your question a minimal form that displays this behaviour

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6DLj/1/).  Looks like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: It seems this bug was already fixed. Google Chrome 28.0.1482.0 canary has no problem.